# Sorting data structure: random in, lowest out

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I need a data structure that supports the insertion of key-value pairs, and the extraction of the pair with the lowest key. Insertion and extraction can happen at any time, thus the data structure must remain continuously sorted, and extraction includes the removal of the pair from the list. Additionally, no new pair that is being inserted can have a key lower in value than the key of the most recently extracted pair. The keys of the pairs being inserted will also increase in value over time.

Requirements:

- Key: 64-bit unsigned integer
- Maximum number of entries listed at any one time: ~10^6
- Entries inserted (and extracted) per second: ~10^5
- Efficient removal of entries upon extraction
- Keys of pairs being inserted: current lowest key > key > current lowest key + 10^7
- Memory requirements are irrelevant, computational complexity is not
- Some pairs can have the same key

Comment: I have not tried any solutions so far, but i have had some thoughts about it:

Comment: @user1062874 Well... what are your thoughts?

Comment: Implementing it as a circular buffer of small arrays, then simply traversing the circular buffer and sorting the arrays to get the elements in order. +very fast insertion -possibly slow retrieval of last element -limited maximum value of key

Comment: Using a self balancing binary search tree would also do the trick, but with O(log n) insertion

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic. :) :)

Comment: When you say memory requirements are irrelevant, do you expect the enough memory to keep the entire data structure in memory all the time? Please clarify. ...Never mind, you do mention a 64 bit integer as the index.

Comment: What does “The keys of the pairs being inserted will also increase in value over time” mean?  Are you just reiterating that “no new pair that is being inserted can have a key lower in value than the key of the most recently extracted pair”, or do you mean that keys of items already in the structure will occasionally increase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A binary heap is an excellent choice, as others have suggested. I've found that they perform quite well in most situations. A [*d*-ary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-ary_heap) (with *d* being 3 or 4), can give you a good 10% performance increase with very little added implementation complexity. In my experiments with heaps of the size you're talking about, a 3-ary heap was noticeably faster than a binary (2-ary) heap.

Another option is a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list), which would give you O(log n) insertion and O(1) removal of the lowest. Implementing a skip list is slightly more involved than a binary heap, it requires a little more memory, and the constant factors are higher. Insertion likely will be slightly slower than in a heap, but removal would be significantly faster. Whether it's faster enough to make up for the additional memory cost and increased implementation complexity is something you'd have to answer yourself.

Comment: +1 for mentioning skip lists. I completely forgot about those, they would certainly be worth looking into for this project

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing sounds very much like a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue), with the priority determined by key comparison.

The ideal implementation would be a [binary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), as this results in `O(log n)` insertion *and* deletion, which will be better overall than one being `O(1)` and the other being `O(n)`. If you expect to have very few insertions or removals, you could use a sorted or unsorted sequence for your implementation, but I would still be hesitant to do so.

As far as the requirement about inserted elements having keys greater than the last removed element, this would simply require an additional member variable indicating the value of the last removed key; just update this every time you remove. Doing so will not affect asymptotic runtime. Alternatively, you could have a variable in your code that you check against insertion candidates before you call the insertion method. Either way, you need to store the key of the last removed element and compare it against the element to insert before calling the insert method.

Answer (score 2):

One option is the [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue), which satisfies your requirement --- random in, lowest out, it performs `O(logn)` to insert and remove (pop).